# Android add all object to list after loop

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I try to add all object to list after I finish the loop.
Here is my method in adapter that I want to add.

```
public MusicCustomAdapter(Context context) {
            songList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.context = context;
}

public void addMoreItem(List<SongRespones.Songs> songList) {
                this.songList = songList;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

This is my callResponse using Retrofit:

```
    private void getAllSongBySinger() {
            songService = ServiceGenerator.createService(SongService.class);
            Call<SongRespones> callAllSong = songService.findAllSongBySinger();
            callAllSong.enqueue(new Callback<SongRespones>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<SongRespones> call, Response<SongRespones> response) {
                    List<SongRespones.Songs> listSong;
                    SongRespones songRespones = response.body();
                    listSong = songRespones.getSongs();
                    for (SongRespones.Songs songs : listSong) {
                        if (songs.getSinger().getId() == getSingerId) {
                            Log.e(LOG, songs + "");
                            adapter.addMoreItem(What must I input in here?);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<SongRespones> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        }
```

Please help me:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you only want to show selected singer's song. So basically in your `onResponse` method create new list and add the songs you want to show and finally update your adapter with this list.

```
                SongRespones songRespones = response.body();
                List<SongRespones.Songs> listSong = songRespones.getSongs();
                List<SongRespones.Songs> selectedSingersSongs = new Arraylist();
                for (SongRespones.Songs songs : listSong) {
                    if (songs.getSinger().getId() == getSingerId) {
                        Log.e(LOG, songs + "");
                        selectedSingersSongs.add(songs);
                    }
                }                    
                adapter.addMoreItem(selectedSingersSongs);
```

And of course you should `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` before

Comment: @santaluThank you so much, sir I followed you, Now it's working:D

Comment: Glad to help you. Can you accept the answer please?

Comment: santalu , Yes I can